# My Laptop suddenly shuts down when the battery is on 75%

Tags: battery

I have an ASUS A455LB laptop, recently i replaced the battery bcs it broke. But after i replaced it with new battery, and run on Battery Mode, my laptop suddenly shut down completely.

The battery indicator says it still got 75% battery left.

When I turn on my laptop again, it shuts down again on the elementary OS logo screen..

My laptop runs fine on AC mode.

This is the system that i used.

[image: System Desc]

This is the details about the battery 
[image]

Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks..

Comment: Have you considered returning the battery? It might be faulty. I had some issues in the past that turned out to be a hardware problem instead of software problem. So don't forget that option.

Comment: i did return the battery, and all the problem is solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on hardware, i replaced the battery with a new one. Everything back to normal